# How content appears like image

Tags: html

Let say we have the following form code

```
<form action="post" method="post" name="form">
Your Name :  <input name="name" type="text" id="name">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

what if i want it to be viewed as image

Why ! in fact i've text-area where i will put some HTML codes and i want the output of that code appears normally as web-browser view but as image , means no way to click on it or operate just appears as image

I do not know if it possible or not but i wonder it it can be and here is example for exactly how this forms i wants to appears

[image: http://i.imm.io/aJOy.jpeg | Example for output of that code]

output of the html codes appears as image

so any method any help any function or class can do like this ?!

Thanks

Comment: you can make the inputs non-editable.

Comment: You would need some kind of HTML rendering engine and a way of converting the result to an image. Maybe you could simulate the intended behavior by using the GD library to draw an image that *resembles* formular elements.

Comment: please keep in mind that PHP is a text preprocessor, not HTML rendering engine.

Comment: Rendering a picture of this is not possible (without some advanced stuff). Disable and style the inputs like already suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it two ways

1. Put and transparent block element over it (position: absolute and so on)
2. disable every input element (disabled:disabled attribute)

see:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp